# Confused about this contract code

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am having trouble understanding the function `confirmAndCheck` (line 149 in the [Wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol#L149) contract). Pasting the code below, with my addition in the last line:

```
function confirmAndCheck(bytes32 _operation) internal returns (bool) {
        // determine what index the present sender is:
        uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)];
        // make sure they're an owner
        if (ownerIndex == 0) return;

        var pending = m_pending[_operation];
        // if we're not yet working on this operation, switch over and reset the confirmation status.
        if (pending.yetNeeded == 0) {
            // reset count of confirmations needed.
            pending.yetNeeded = m_required;
            // reset which owners have confirmed (none) - set our bitmap to 0.
            pending.ownersDone = 0;
            pending.index = m_pendingIndex.length++;
            m_pendingIndex[pending.index] = _operation;
        }
        // determine the bit to set for this owner.
        uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex;
        // make sure we (the message sender) haven't confirmed this operation previously.
        if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit == 0) {
            Confirmation(msg.sender, _operation);
            // ok - check if count is enough to go ahead.
            if (pending.yetNeeded <= 1) {
                // enough confirmations: reset and run interior.
                delete m_pendingIndex[m_pending[_operation].index];
                delete m_pending[_operation];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // not enough: record that this owner in particular confirmed.
                pending.yetNeeded--;
                pending.ownersDone |= ownerIndexBit;
                // m_pending[_operation] = pending; // ?
            }
        }
    }
```

In case of multiple confirmations, shouldn't we save the local variable `pending` inside `m_pending`, since it will be accessed again later in [line 155](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol#L155)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a [reference type](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#reference-types), so we shouldn’t.

> On the other hand, assignments from a memory stored reference type to
>   another memory-stored reference type does not create a copy.

Since the variable `pending` is reference, all changes applied to this variable are also applied to the origin. Therefore we don’t have to assign its value back to `m_pending`.

Comment: This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: @niksmac What’s the problem?

Comment: Link only answers are generally not welcome, will get removed eventually.

Comment: Consider adding some information the link into this answer.

Comment: @niksmac Is it ok now?

Comment: now looks good, +1